# mod_wsgi on Python 3.10 does not update Django templates without Apache restart

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, python-3.10

I have been running a Django server on Python 3.8 with Apache and mod_wsgi for some time now, and decided it was time to upgrade to Python 3.10. I installed Python 3.10 on my server, installed the Django and mod_wsgi packages, copied the 3.10 build of mod_wsgi.so to Apache's modules folder, and everything works great ... however, it seems with this build of mod_wsgi, changes to template files do not take effect unless I restart Apache.

As an example, I added a random HTML template file to my website, and started the server with some initial text in that template. Running on the Python 3.8, I am able to change the contents of that template (e.g. `echo "More Text" >> test_template.html`) and upon refreshing my browser the new text will show up. However doing the same test in 3.10, the new text will *not* show up. I have tried different browser sessions and hard reloading, it is not a caching issue on the client side, and looking at the response sizes in Apache's access log confirms the data being sent to the client changes in 3.8 but not in 3.10.

I have stood up a test server to isolate the problem, and have narrowed it down to specifically changing the mod_wsgi build (which of course changes the entire Python version used by Django). Still, that confirms it should not be a caching setting of Apache, or any mis-configuration of Django templates, and I have followed the steps [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#embedded-or-daemon-mode) to confirm I am running mod_wsgi in Daemon mode (as I have been for years on this server, this is a long-standing server configured seemingly without issue for Python 3.8).

Lastly, running the Django development server (using base `manage.py runserver` command) reflects template changes on the fly without issue, and without a server reboot. So as far as I can tell this seems to be a mod_wsgi quirk.

The specific Apache | mod_wsgi | Python version combinations is as follows:

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.9.4 Python/3.10

...as reported by Apache's error.log, confirming the modules are loading as expected.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue with Python 3.10 builds of mod_wsgi? Perhaps is there a new setting I'm forgetting? My understanding of Django templates is that they should always reflect changes immediately (without a server restart), however code changes require a restart (or touching of the wsgi.py script); I have never had to restart the server for template changes prior to this change. Any help is appreciated-

Edit: Just tried upgrading my Python 3.8 version of mod_wsgi to the same version (4.9.4), and it still works fine, so there is something about Python 3.10 vs 3.8, or another installed python package. I will keep testing...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making a post under the mod_wsgi github project, and traced the issue back to a change in Django's behavior in [this](https://github.com/django/django/commit/bf7c51a5f4da5f00b46923545ea6657ba9556bf6) commit

Full details of that post can be found [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/821)

Tl;dr; is there is a caching template loader, which used to only be enabled when `DEBUG = False` was set, but was updated to always be in effect. I'm not sure why my Python 3.8 build did not have this change, as I had upgraded both builds to the latest Django build available (4.6.1), but my original install was years ago so it's quite possible a fresh install would not have had this issue.

If you still want to disable cached templates as I did, you have to override the template loaders in your Django settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'OPTIONS': {
            'loaders': ['django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader']
        },
    },
]
```